# ReferenceError when calling custom function

Tags: javascript

1. I have a function which is being called on a button click. 
      function account_verify()
   {  var user
   = $("#user").val();
   var pwd = $("#pwd").val();  var req = 'user='+user+'&pwd='+pwd+'&wlanusermac='+wlanusermac+'&wlanuserip='+wlanuserip+'&wlanbssid='+wlanbssid+'&wlanssid='+wlanssid+'&wlanapmac='+wlanapmac;
   $.ajax({
           type: "POST",       dataType: "text",       data: req,      processData:    false,      url: "account_verify.php",      success:
   account_verify_success,         error: account_verify_fail  }); }

                  
                   User Name：
                                           
                   Password：

   ```
               <input type="button" id="lLogin" value="login" onClick="account_verify()">
               <input type="button" id="lClear" value="Cancel" onClick="document.getElementById('user').value = document.getElementById('pwd').value = '';"><br>
               </td>
               <td></td>           </tr>   </table>     </body> </html>
   ```

   Uncaught ReferenceError: account_verify is not defined
            What am I missing?

Comment: How you call this function?? Please post that too

Comment: <input type="button" id="lLogin" value="login" onClick="account_verify()"> @Abdulla

Comment: Is the javascript loaded at the moment you call the function?

Comment: yes loading parameters..but calling on the basis of button click.

Comment: Can you post the whole code of your script (including the page where your button is)? I suspect, that your JavaScript isn't loaded correctly.

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function account_verify() {
        var user = $("#user").val();
        var pwd = $("#pwd").val();
        var req = 'user=' + user + '&pwd=' + pwd + '&wlanusermac=' + wlanusermac + '&wlanuserip=' + wlanuserip + '&wlanbssid=' + wlanbssid + '&wlanssid=' + wlanssid + '&wlanapmac=' + wlanapmac;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: req,
            url: 'account_verify.php',
            success:function(data)
            {

            }
            error:function(data)
            {

            }
        });
    }
</script>
```